# Skip document in Cosmos DB container if the deserialization fails

Tags: c#, exception, serialization, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following code for reading the documents from a Cosmos DB container:

```
        var result = new List<StoredLead>();
        var linqSerializerOptions = new CosmosLinqSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.CamelCase
        };
        var iterator = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<StoredLead>(false, null, null, linqSerializerOptions).Where(expression).ToFeedIterator();

        while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
        {
            var list = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
            foreach (var lead in list)
            {
                //Do some stuff with the lead
                result.Add(lead);
            }
        }

        return result;
```

If the JSON document has incorrect value in any field (string instead of int, or int instead of date/time) I get `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException` which causes the whole batch of objects read from the container to be discarded. I wonder if it possible to skip documents which cannot be deserialized and proceed with the document which are deserialized successfully.

I tried to create a custom `CosmosSerializer` with following code:

```
public class SerliarizationService : CosmosSerializer
    {
        private readonly JsonSerializer serializer;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public SerliarizationService(ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            serializer = new JsonSerializer
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore                    
            };
            serializer.Error += HandleError;
        }

        private void HandleError(object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs args)
        {
            // only log an error once
            if (args.CurrentObject == args.ErrorContext.OriginalObject)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Error while deserializing document. Error message: {errorMessage}", args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
                args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

I.e. I try to log and suppress the errors when deserialization exceptions occur but the behavior is not quite as I want. It seems to set default value to the fields which cannot be successfully deserialized, which is not want I want to achieve.

Comment: You can always use JObject instead and attempt the conversion from JObject to your type afterwards for each document and handle the individual failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```cs
var iterator = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<StoredLead>()
    .Where(x => x.PartitionKey == "example")
    .Select(x => (object) x)
    .Select(x => (JToken) x)
    .ToFeedIterator();

var results = new List<StoredLead>();
while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    foreach (var item in await iterator.ReadNextAsync())
    {
        try
        {
            results.Add(item.ToObject<StoredLead>());
        }
        catch 
        { 
            //no implementation
        }
    }
}
```

By returning the item as a `JToken` you can iterate over it and deserialize each entry seperately. The `Select` statements are there to allow you to use strongly typed linq expressions, but still return the results of the query as a `JToken`.

Comment: Great! This is much neater implementation than I came to :) Thanks.